# bash not increasing counter

Tags: bash, counter, assign

well i just dont know what happened, my grep results counter used to work and now
it seems that no matter what i do it doesn't count my results and stay on the
initial value of 0, at the first line of the script i initiating it:

> TotalResults=0

even if i define it in that way:

> typeset -i TotalResults=0

it won't work , that's the while loop which in it the counter should grow and it actually doing the other commands, it's doing the printf stuff but just not increasing the counter, i checked it with echo and also when i want to use it, it stays on 0!

> export URL="$CurrentURL"
>
> grep -n -o -a $ExpressionValue $INDEX | while read line ; do
>
> ```
>       printf "%s\t%s" "${URL} ${line}"
>       printf "\n"
>       let TotalResults+=1
> ```
>
> done

what is the problem? I have other counter that defined the same and he is working great, I'm tired of that, please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are incrementing the counter in a subshell, after the |. The variable does not change in the parent shell. Change your code to

```
while read line ; do

      printf "%s\t%s" "${URL} ${line}"
      printf "\n"
      let TotalResults+=1

done < <(grep -n -o -a $ExpressionValue $INDEX)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use counter in c-style,  as code became more readable and works faster:

```
while read line ; do

      printf "%s\t%s" "${URL} ${line}"
      printf "\n"
      (( ++TotalResults))

done < <(grep -n -o -a $ExpressionValue $INDEX)
```